# yum Error: No module named site

Tags: centos, yum, python

I installed Greenplum on Centos 7 and now I cannot use yum.

I need to install samba-client but when I run:

```
yum install samba-client
```

I see this error: `ImportError: No module named site`

```
which python
/usr/local/greenplum-db/ext/python/bin/python
python -V
Python 2.6.2
cat $PYTHONHOME
cat: /usr/local/greenplum-db/./ext/python: Is a directory
```

No idea how this happened. I notice that my other servers do not have this problem and display `python 2.7.5`

Comment: @Rahul unset worked thanks. Would this have something to do with environment variables in bashrc?

Comment: Please add your answer so that others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`PYTHONHOME`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME)

> Change the location of the standard Python libraries. By default, the
>   libraries are searched in prefix/lib/pythonversion and
>   exec_prefix/lib/pythonversion, where prefix and exec_prefix are
>   installation-dependent directories, both defaulting to /usr/local.
>
> When PYTHONHOME is set to a single directory, its value replaces both
>   prefix and exec_prefix. To specify different values for these, set
>   PYTHONHOME to prefix:exec_prefix.

In a shell you can use these commands to clean up those :

```
unset PYTHONPATH

## to use the system default ##
unset PYTHONHOME
```